# How to find the apk's is available or not from another apk in android

Tags: android, apk

I have an android application which contains four modules(I mean four apk's).Each module has separate apk.But dependency is more among all the apk's. If all apk's available then my application works fine.But the problem is user can un-install any apk at any time.At that time application will crash. How to solve this problem. Is there anyway to find the availability of checking the apk's availability through programmatically ?.Or suggest me regarding this issue.

Please suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Regards
Murthy

Comment: When does you application crash? While trying to invoke activity from un-installed APK or some other case?

Comment: Yes while invoke an activity from un-installed APK. How to prevent that ? .Through programmatically we have to handle try-catch mechanism or any other way. Please let me know if another way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your apk is a data provider you can try to ask it for some data and catch the error.

Answer (score 1):

If the 4 modules are dependent of each-other, I cannot see any reason you should release them as 4 seperate APK's. I'd suggest you release them as one APK, and solve your problems like that.

Comment: Those modules are run independently also.But in some cases other three modules want some data from module-1.So at that point of time how can i know whether that apk1 is available or not?

Comment: THat's not really clear from your question. Could you perhaps update it to reflect what is an acceptable situation? Will/should there be users that install only 3 of the apks? Why would they want that? Because of space? Why do you need them to be separate?

Comment: I want the information regarding how to find the apk is available or not through programmatically from another apk. (or) how to find the apk is available in the device or not, throgh programmatically from another application in that device.

Comment: Yes, you said that. You also asked for suggestions regarding the issue, and the best suggestion I can give is trying to avoid a situation where you have to rely on things that are not under your control. Now the rude way would be just to call an intent and see if you get an error and catch that, but that's a bit hack-ish.